# How to not merge all js into one file in Rails 3.2?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, configuration

I use Rails 3.2. I am using a lot of JS gems, and most of them require to be called in specific order. In development it automatically seperates different JS files like this :

```
<link href="/assets/companies.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/contacts.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/fake_json.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But in production it merges all of the files like this :

```
<script src="/assets/application-e30cf15d1afc4b59752074fa16cd83a3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In my specific case, I do not want or require Rails to do this for me. I tried to cancel this by using `config.assets.compress = false` and `config.assets.debug = true` in `production.rb` file, but it has no effect even after restarting the server.

How do I enable "not merging" on production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following line to the `production.rb`

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

Check the [Configuring Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-assets) for other useful parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If the reason you don't want them all merged is that they need to be loaded in a specific order, and the default is compiling them alphabetically, you can get rid of the

```
require_tree
```

line in application.js and write out separate require statements in the order in which you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps have a `javascript_include_tag :application, :defer => true, :debug => false` in a view?

Your questions helped me with a similar issue (+1). I needed to set `config.assets.debug = true` in `development.rb` and `<%= javascript_include_tag :application, :defer => true, :debug => true %>` in `shared/_settings.html.erb`